# What are some "app" basics from the first phase?

Tags: android, iphone

Our current shopping cart is Magento so do we use our custom code plus Magento code or is this potential app built with a completely different scripting language? And if so, what is it? Also, are their languages for Android AND Apple or just something else entirely?

If your boss said he wants an app, what is the first step?

Comment: The first step is to research (on your own). There is no shortage of information available online. StackOverflow is not an appropriate forum for such initial research or broad / open-ended question. However, when there is a *specific* question about a *specific* problem..

Answer (score 0):

I believe Android apps for the 'play store' are coded in Java, and iOS apps for the 'app store' are coded in swift.

Comment: The main language for Apple Apps is Swift *or* Objective-C. Also there are a number of other [sub-]platforms like JavaScript cross-overs, Unity, etc.